# Clickable links in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, hyperlink, datadetectortypes

I'm trying to add clickable text in a UITableViewCell, I tried some different approaches:

- I've tried using 3rd party label such as fancyLabel etc, but the problem with those is that they don't support right to left languages (they always start the text from left to right)
- I've tried using UIWebView as the text view but when I add a UIWebView to a UITableViewCell and scroll the table fast the text inside the webView is empty and when the scrolling decelerate the text reappears again, so it doesn't look good
- I can't use UITextView because it doesn't support custom UIDataDetectionTypes and I need to detect # and @ for tweeter links

Any idea on how to approach the issue???

Answer (score 0):

Create a borderless `UIButton` and style it so it looks like a link (buttons support left / right aligned text as well), and when clicked just launch a web view with the link contents.

Comment: the text is a paragraph not a single word and I would like to link only specific words in that paragraph